# socket_connect is working, but not socket_bind showing warring

Tags: php, sockets

With my code, I can connect properly but socket bind is not working please help me.

Showing this error:

> Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testingServer/socket.php on line 35
>
> socket_bind() failed: reason: Cannot assign requested address
>
> Warning:  socket_listen(): unable to listen on socket [22]: Invalid argument in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testingServer/socket.php on line 39
>
> socket_listen() failed: reason: Invalid argument

Here's the code :

```
$address = '192.168.0.250';
$port = 8050;
/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
// echo $port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');  

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
  echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "<pre/>";
    print_r($sock);
    echo "Socket created"; echo "<br/>";
} 
 // check ip and port showing online or offline
 if (!$socket = @fsockopen($address, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3)) {
        echo "Offline!";
    } else {
        echo "Online!";
        fclose($socket);
    } 

 $result = socket_connect($sock, $address, $port) ;
 var_dump($result);
 if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . 
          socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
} 

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock,3) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

 $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg)); 
socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Connecting automatically binds an unused local port - you cannot `bind` a second time, and `listen` can only be done on an unconnected port.

Comment: Actually , we are trying to connect global payment machine for swipe the card so i WANT TO SEND PAYMENT INFORMATION TO PAYMWENT DEVICE. we got it only IP and port number . this IP FOR PAYMENT DEVICE WHICH IS CONNECTED to System.

Comment: Probably you only need to create a socket and connect it to the payment site. That's what `fsockopen` does. You can likely drop the rest. (You're actually creating two sockets now: one with `socket_create` and one with `fsockopen`.)

Comment: Thanks now its working